# how can we create subdomain dynamically using vhost . I have to share some data in username.domain.com and subdomain created only after user signup

Tags: node.js, vhosts

I am trying with express vhost but i dont know how to create dynamically that means if a user signup with that username create a subdomain like username.domain.com

my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const morgan = require("morgan");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
require("dotenv").config({ path: __dirname + "/.env" });
const vhost = require("vhost");

const subdomain = express();

const domain = "localhost";

app.use(vhost(`username.${domain}`, subdomain));

app.use(cookieParser());
subdomain.use(cookieParser());

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

subdomain.use(morgan("dev"));
subdomain.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
subdomain.use(bodyParser.json());

const userRoutes = require("./api/routes/user");

subdomain.use(userRoutes);

app.use("*", (req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not found");
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
});

app.use("*", (error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message,
    },
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**Here i create subdomain manualy like http://username.localhost:3000/user**

I want to create it dynamicaly after user signup using an API

Comment: can anyone suggest me a solution

Comment: please help someone